# Are passwordless logins like ##MS_SQLResourceSigningCertificate## , ##MS_AgentSigningCertificate## a vulnerability?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, security, users, logins

I'm new to MS SQL Server.

Colleagues working in IT security, have run an scan showing come DB users with null password.

Some of them are ( # included )

```
##MS_SQLResourceSigningCertificate##
##MS_SQLReplicationSigningCertificate##
##MS_SQLAuthenticatorCertificate##
##MS_PolicySigningCertificate##
##MS_SmoExtendedSigningCertificate##
##MS_AgentSigningCertificate##
```

I suspect they are not a security threat but, since they don't use Windows Authentication either, I don't know how to support that assumption.

What are these logins for ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These logins are created from a certificate.  In fact, if you run the following query:

```
select 
    name,
    type_desc
from sys.server_principals
where type = 'c';
```

You will see that they are of type `CERTIFICATE_MAPPED_LOGIN`.  *They are used typically to sign code*.  And you cannot use a certificate mapped login to connect with SQL Server.  Please see this BOL reference on [`CREATE LOGIN`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189751.aspx):

> Logins created from certificates or asymmetric keys are used only for code signing. **They cannot be used to connect to SQL Server**.